# Calling a cl in a particular unit eg XXX or YYY using asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net, ibm-midrange

I want to call a program using QSYS.----- but I want it to execute in a particular unit eg XXX or YYY or TTT  but it is not executing

Below is the code in ASP.net C#

```
As400CMD = "CALL DEVLSLIB/EBANK_REVS";
sql = "CALL QSYS.QCMDEXC('" + As400CMD + "',00000000" + 
         As400CMD.Length.ToString() + ".00000)";
lodbcCommand = new OdbcCommand(sql, DbConn);
lodbcCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
DbConn.Open();
lodbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
DbConn.Close();
```

and the CL I am calling is executing fine but fails to execute the last part   to apply input. But I seem not to know how to tell the system to use which unit when applying the input

```
    PGM                                     
           CALL       PGM(EQXREC) PARM(LIBRARY)    
    ENDPGM
```

Comment: What do you mean by execute a particular unit? And why do you have `LIBRARY` as a parameter to program `EQXREC`? You aren't trying to execute EQXREC in library `LIBRARY` are you? In that case the correct syntax is `CALL PGM(LIBRARY/EQXREC)`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am guessing you don't know the general format for IBM i commands. It is this:

```
COMMAND KEYWORD(VALUE) KEYWORD(VALUE) ...
```

The `KEYWORD(VALUE)` construct is like a parameter, but I don't really want to call it that because the call command has a keyword called `PARM` for parameters. The `CALL` command looks like this:

```
CALL PGM(program name) PARM(parameter list)
```

Sometimes you can omit the `KEYWORD` and just pass some parameters positionally. Some of the `KEYWORD`s must be typed out using the full `KEYWORD(VALUE)` syntax. In the case of the `CALL` command the `KEYWORD`s can be omitted, but since the `PARM` value is a list, it must be enclosed by parenthesis `()` like this:

```
CALL program (parameter list)
```

---

In your example:

```
As400CMD = "CALL DEVLSLIB/EBANK_REVS";
sql = "CALL QSYS.QCMDEXC('" + As400CMD + "',00000000" + 
         As400CMD.Length.ToString() + ".00000)";
```

is attempting to call program EBANK_REVS in library DEVLSLIB with no parameters. Incidently, `"',00000000" + As400CMD.Length.ToString() + ".00000)"` could be replaced with `"', " + As400CMD.Length.ToString())"`. You don't need all those zeros.

You don't tell us what the name of the CL you provided, but if it is indeed EBANK_REVS in library DEVLSLIB, then that is all you need to do. Unless, there is something you haven't told us.

Comment: Whe I run the command CALL PGM(EQXREC) PARM(LIBRARY) it works when on the AS400 iseries but when I call the rpgl from C# it seems like its not recognising  the library list so as to execute

Comment: You are executing `EBANK_REVS` not `EQXREC` from C#.

Comment: In addition, it is likely that the library list is different between your interactive job and the ODBC server job.